# Saving Workbook in Python using xlwt gives error

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

This problem has been happening to me a lot lately. 
When I run this code:

```
import xlwt
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = wb.add_sheet("Random")
sheet.write(0,0,"hello!")
wb.save("test.xls")
```

It gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module2>", line 16, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 662, in save
    doc.save(filename, self.get_biff_data())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt\CompoundDoc.py", line 261, in save
    f = open(file_name_or_filelike_obj, 'w+b')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test.xls'
```

I've searched for the answer, but I couldn't find it. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: it's probably open somewhere. or you can't write to that file. try specifying a full path.

Comment: If I specify the full path, it gives me another error:                  f = open(file_name_or_filelike_obj, 'w+b')
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w+b') or filename: 'C:\\test.xls'

Comment: Well, I finally found out why it wasn't working. I was running this program, but I hadn't saved it. I had to first save it, and then run it.

Comment: glad you sorted it out.